# Как осуществить распознавание лиц с онлайн веб камеры на python?

Tags: python, opencv

Я хочу осуществить распознавание лиц, но не могу найти информацию как получать поток видео в реальном времени, с самим ИИ проблем не имею. Вот пример камеры с которой я хочу получать изображение https://camera.lipetsk.ru/index.php?r=camera/video&id=2061. Так же, буду благодарен если подскажете как сравнивать лица имея допустим фото человека, как сделать скриншот в момент нахождения человека на видео и сохранить его. Использую библиотеки openCV, face recognition python. Заранее спасибо, добрый человек.

Comment: https://proglib.io/p/pishem-programmu-dlya-avtomaticheskogo-raspoznavaniya-obektov-s-veb-kamer-2019-10-05 прям далеко ходить не нужно. Все ваши вопросы неплохо гуглятся. И очень странно, что у вас нет проблем с ИИ, но вы не знаете как сравнить фото человека и человека на видео...

Comment: Я не нашел как можно получать видео с сайта и добавить его в openCV